# Defining measure on homeomorphic spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Say you have two homeomorphic spaces $X\cong Y$, and a measure $\mu$ defined on the measurable space $(X,\scr{B}$$(X))$, where $\scr B$$(X)$ is the Borel sigma-algebra of $X$. Since $\scr B$$(X)$ is generate by the open sets of $X$, and $U\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(U)\subseteq Y$ is open, isn't it true that $\mu$ is also a measure on $(Y,\scr B$$(X))$, with $\mu(U)=\mu(f(U))$?

Comment: If $\mu$ is allready a measure on one of them and the spaces are not the same then $\mu$ is *not* a measur on the other. This in spite of being homeomorphic. However, it has indeed a corresponding measure $\nu$ on the other defined by $\nu(U)=\mu(f(U))$.

Comment: @drhab: worth adding that there's nothing "special" about $\nu$ since first of all it may not be unique.